# The difference between passing query params in a webservice

Tags: java, ajax

What is the difference between passing query params as `/cars/id/toyota` vs `/cars?id=toyota` in a webservice?

Is one REST vs other web service type?

Comment: A more rest-like uri would be `/cars/toyota` imo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing parameter in Rest service in the form of Url or query string, both have different significance.
In simple words

1. `/cars/id/toyota` in this toyta is variable and your service expecting something after `id/{variablename}` otherwise it gives an error (endpoint not found). So in this case your variable became mandatory.
2. `/cars?id=toyota` in this case your query string (Id) becomes optional.
   So use query string whenever you want to make that variable optional. :)

Answer (score 0):

Nothing, obviously–it all depends on how the consuming service expects to retrieve parameters.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the receiving party (your web server and the framework you use on that web-service). Both or neither could conceivably be REST web-services, depending on your implementation.

Conceptually, the difference lies in the path from the web-server root (`/`) and parameters:

`/cars/id/toyota` is a URL to path `/cars/id/toyota` without parameters

`/cars?id=toyota` is a URL to path `/cars` with parameter named `id` with value `toyota`

Comment: Many frameworks automatically recognize certain patterns and convert them from one form into another. Wikipedia is a good example (even though it is PHP based). `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/REST` is automatically converted to `http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=REST`. If you have more questions, it would be helpful to know about a specific framework that you will be using.